# AuthZForce FIWARE in Cosmos

Tags: fiware, authzforce

How to use AuthZForce with Cosmos? And how is the configuration of Cosmos to use AuthZForce?

Comment: I think it should be better to have two questions: 1) how to use authzforce with Cosmos, 2) how to use authzforce with Orion. As general rule, make your questions as specific as you can.

Comment: Auth zforce has nothing to do with Cosmos certificates nor Cosmos REST APIs.

Comment: Considering the @frb response, please reformulate the question in terms of Orion, removing references to Cosmos. In addition, fiware-wirecloud label should be removed, as the question has nothing to do with Wirecloud. Once you do that (not before) we will consider the question. Thanks!

Comment: ok, ty :D i change the tag and the qestion

Answer (score 1):

As @frb has said in a comment to this question:

> Auth zforce has nothing to do with Cosmos certificates nor Cosmos REST APIs